# use command find and copy but using a list.txt with names

Tags: bash, find

I have a **list.txt** with different filenames and I want to find all those 3600 filename in subdirectories and then copy to /destination_folder.

Can I use the command find /path/ {file.txt} then copy to /destination_folder ?

The **list.txt** should have the following filenames/lines:

```
test_20180724004008_4270.txt.bz2
test_20180724020008_4278.txt.bz2
test_20180724034009_4288.txt.bz2
test_20180724060009_4302.txt.bz2
test_20180724061009_4303.txt.bz2
test_20180724062010_4304.txt.bz2
test_20180724063010_4305.txt.bz2
test_20180724065010_4307.txt.bz2
test_20180724070010_4308.txt.bz2
test_20180724071010_4309.txt.bz2
test_20180724072010_4310.txt.bz2
test_20180724072815_4311.txt.bz2
test_20180724073507_4312.txt.bz2
test_20180724074608_4314.txt.bz2
test_20180724075041_4315.txt.bz2
test_20180724075450_4316.txt.bz2
test_20180724075843_4317.txt.bz2
test_20180724075843_4317.txt.bz2
test_20180724080207_4318.txt.bz2
test_20180724080522_4319.txt.bz2
test_20180724080826_4320.txt.bz2
test_20180724081121_4321.txt.bz2
................................
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to make a list of all of the files in a directory, then use your list to iterate through the list of files found.

First save your list of files found to a file

```
find . -type f > foundFiles.txt
```

Then you need to use your file to search the other

```
cat list.txt | while read line
do
  if [ `grep -c "${line}" foundFiles.txt` ]
  then
    cp -v $(grep "${line}" foundFiles.txt) /destination_folder/
  fi
done
```

I'll let you take the base and make it into a script for use again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *echo* and *sed*:

```
echo $(sed "s/.*/\"\0\"/;s/^/ -name /;s/$/ -o/;$ s/-o//" list.txt)
```

This outputs a list of files to be used in *find* command:

```
-name "file1.txt.bz2" -o -name "file2.txt.bz2" -o -name "file3.txt.bz2"
```

Then use `-exec cp -t targetDir {} +` in *find* to copy the files:

```
find \( $(eval echo $(sed "s/.*/\"\0\"/;s/^/ -name /;s/$/ -o/;$ s/-o//" list.txt)) \) -exec cp -t targetDir {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the file and append the results to your destination folder:

```
for i in `cat list.txt`; 
do cp `find * -name $i` destination_folder/;
done
```

This finds all the files in `list.txt` and copies those files to `destination_folder/`.

The `` for i in `cat list.txt` `` creates a variable `i` that loops through the entire file.

The `` cp `find * -name $i` destination_folder/ `` finds the path to file and copies it to the `destination_folder/`.